# Bootstrap 5 disabled+checked switch ignored by JS FormData class

Tags: javascript, form-data, bootstrap-5

I have a [Bootstrap 5 switch input](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#switches) which I want to make mandatory (checked by default and not uncheckable). The documentation says you can combine the attributes `checked` and `disabled`. However, the Javascript FormData class seems to ignore disabled inputs, regardless if they are checked. Is there a workaround or can't I use FormData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vanilla Javascript solution is to populate the FormData object by hand:

```js
let form = e.target;
let data = new FormData(form); // Serialize all form elements that are not disabled

// Find all disabled Bootstrap switches ...
let switchInputs = form.querySelectorAll('.form-switch>input[type=checkbox]:disabled');

// ... and append them to the FormData object
switchInputs.forEach(function(input){
    if(input.checked) {
       data.append(input.name, input.value || 'on');   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to submit values from disabled checkboxes in a form,  you can use js to achieve this..

try  (sample code)

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    $('#checkbox-id').each(function(e) {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    })
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I needed a vanilla JS solution. Thanks!